# UITableView not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can someone tell what I am missing in code as it's not displaying anything in the table view. Also I have a delegate and data source already setup in code, and UITableView view outlet.

.h

```
@interface FoodViewController :  UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
NSMutableArray *objects;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tablewviewFood;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  NSMutableArray *objects;
@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
objects =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Employee Services",@"Human           Resources",@"Organization",@"Policies",@"Reference",nil];
 _tablewviewFood.dataSource = self;
  _tablewviewFood.delegate = self;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [_objects count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Celler";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

Comment: Could you show how you set the delegate and data source?

Comment: A point about your `numberOfRowsInSwction:`, your `NSLog` will not run since it is after the return statement.

Comment: Your viewDidLoad is assigning `objects`, did you mean `_objects`?  I'm assuming `_objects` is an iVar for a property?

Comment: @Rob You are right about IB, but it is stated it was done in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary issue is that `viewDidLoad` sets `objects` but `numberOfRowsInSection` deals with `_objects`.

Without seeing your .h file and all your properties and ivars, I would have to guess that you declared a property named `objects` as well as an ivar named `objects`. But you are using either an implicit or explicit `@synthesize objects = _objects`.

This leads to having two ivars, `objects` and `_objects`.

Declare the property but get rid of both the ivar and the `@synthesize`. Then in the code always use `self.objects`.

**Update**: Yes, based on the newly posted code, I was correct.

Comment: [Some background on the concepts](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html) in this answer.